# How to get the start point (lat, lng) and end point (lat, lng) for any particular polygon line in ui-gmap-polygon?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-ICOUBYSBEQVBwSVdKU0JWMms/view?usp=sharing

The above link has a image of map with 5 markers used and using ui-gmap-polygon, I have made the polygon. But I am unable to get the start point lat lng values as well as end point lat lng values as shown in image. I need some event in ui-gmap-polygon which onhover to any polygon lines, gives the object of start point lat lng and end point lat lng. If that kind of event is already present in ui-gmap-polygon, then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Thanks
shub810

Answer (score 0):

You can consult all the x, y points like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getLength(); i++) {
    var xy = polygon.getAt(i);
    console.log (xy);
}
```

You can consult the first point like this:

```
var xy = polygon.getAt(0);
console.log (xy);
```

And the last like this:

```
var xy = polygon.getAt(polygon.getLength()-1);
console.log (xy);
```

However, you have to create your polygon from the start to the end in order to have the same result like this:

```
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},     // Start
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}      // End
  ];
```

You may consult the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygon_add).

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Comment: thanks for answering. I need to know any mouse event can tell if the mouse is on some particular polygon side. For example : if we have a triangle with edge point A, B, C. and assuming mouse is hover on side A-B. Then some polygon mouse event can tell that the mouse is on side A-B.